# If you are running your applications on DC/OS in AWS, is creating an AutoScaling group redundant?

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling, dcos

Since you can enable autoscaling of containers through DC/OS, when running this on an EC2 cluster, is it still necessary to, or redundant to run your cluster in an AutoScaling cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two (orthogonal) concepts here at play and unfortunately the term 'auto-scale' is ambiguous here:

- Certain IaaS platforms (incl. AWS) support dynamically adding VMs to a cluster.
- The other is the capability of a container orchestrator to scale the number of copies of a service—in case of Marathon this is called instances or replicas in the context of Kubernetes—as long as there are sufficient resources (CPU, RAM, etc.) available in the cluster,

In the simplest case you'd auto-scale the services up to the point where the overall cluster utilization is high (>60%? >70%? >80%?) and the use the IaaS-level auto-scaling functionality to add further nodes. Turns out scaling back is the trickier thing.

So, complementary rather than redundant.